# Check if is query last in PDO FETCH PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

How can we check if fetched elem is last of pdo fetch element in while loop?

Example:

```
while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

if($row==[lastofPDOrow])
echo 'last of rows';
}
```

Thanks for helps

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to know if it is the last element? Do you want to print only the last element is that it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $rowCount = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $rowCount++;

        if($rowCount == $result->rowCount())
            echo 'last of rows';
    }

?>
```